# make dataframe from data in textfile

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I got textfile in unorganized way that I need to make from it an organized dataframe.

```
I used the code:
text = sc.textFile(...)
log = text.map (...).filter(...)
```

so each element in log is in the following format from the text:

```
name: server-link
description: success scanning 
auth_code: 123456789
```

now, I want to make a dataframe with the column names ['Name', 'Description', 'auth_code'] that will be contains all the information from all the elements in log.

How can i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

One way of building dataframes is to first create a normal python list of lists, where the first line contains the column headings, and the rest of the lines are the dataframe values. Such a list-list is then turned into a dataframe by the command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:], columns=table[0])
```

In your case you want to read your input three lines at a time and from that build the table. E.g. something like (not tested):

```
lines = text.split('\n')
table = [('name','description','auth_code')]
i=0
while i<len(lines):
    row = [line[3*i+j].split(': ')[1] 
           for j in range(3)]
    table += [row]
    i+= 1
df = pd.DataFrame(table[1:],columns=table[0])
```